# Need help in connection string problem

Tags: c#, connection-string

Though I have given the correct connection string parameter its throwing the exception:

**the connectionstring property has not been initialized**

The connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=server;Database=database;Integrated Security=True;User ID=username;Password=userpassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are those **'s in your connection string, or are they just in there in StackOverflow?  Also, are you ending your <ConnectionString> section?  Can you post the code that throws the error?

Comment: Please show your code where you attempt to use the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you might not be assigning the connection string when you create your connection; can you show the section of code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

In your connection string you gave IntegratedSeccurity = True .
How are you connecting to DB using SQL authentication or windows authentication .If you are using sqlauthentication set it to false and try .